# Is this an image of Kim Jong-un with a nuclear warhead?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, north-korea

In April 2016, the BBC News web-site published *[North Korea nuclear tests: what did they achieve?](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-17823706)*, which evaluated a March 2016 announcement that had made a nuclear warhead that would fit in a missile.

It included this photo and caption:

> [image: Kim Jong-un appears to be inspecting a nuclear warhead]
>
> North Korea's state media showed a picture of Kim Jong-Un inspecting the purported nuclear warhead

Is this an authentic picture of [Kim Jong-Un](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-un) with a nuclear weapon (or prototype)?

Comment: I've seen a few pictures of nukes, and none looked like that.  True, the device would likely be roughly spherical, but would not be likely to have such a smooth exterior.  I'd expect to see something closer to the [Fat Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man) device.  (If it were just the "core" it would be unlikely to have that odd-shaped connector sticking out.)

Comment: I am having trouble imagining a definite answer which meets skeptics standards. The North Koreans could make a fancy polished steel sphere for photo ops, or they could make a real bomb. All of the news coverage I have seen has a heavy component of "we really don't know what is going on."

Comment: @Oddthinking if you can't prove otherwise the burden of proof is on your side like with any claim.

Comment: @Grasper: Sorry, you lost me.

Comment: This is not answerable. Voted to close.